# Why is mat-icon not a know element?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I keep getting error *NG8001: 'mat-icon' is not a known element* when I build my angular project.  I tried downgrading angular material from 16 to 15 to 12, but still the error persists.

Here is my **app.component.html**

```
<div class="page-container">
  <header>
    <div>
      <button mat-button class="menu-button">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <a routerLink="/">
        <span class="app-title">Hamburger Menu Demo</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Here is my **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'side-nav';
}
```

Here is my **app.module.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppComponent,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatIconModule,
    NgModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here are my current angular versions

```
@angular-devkit/build-angular   16.1.5
@angular-devkit/core            16.1.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      16.1.5
@angular/cdk                    16.1.5
@angular/cli                    16.1.5
@angular/material               12.2.13
@schematics/angular             16.1.5
```

There are no other components in the project.  What am I missing?

Comment: I doubt that the compatibility issue when you use Angular 16 with Angular Material 12. You should use the Angular Material version with same *major* version number (16) as your Angular version. Meanwhile, why you need import `NgModule`? By right it shouldn't be import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to diagnose without having access to the full project.

That said...

Your `app.module.ts` looks to be incorrect and should look like this.

The `NgModule` in imports will cause a compilation error and throw the error you are getting.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And as stated above why not use `"@angular/material": "^16.1.5",` ?

Comment: I upgraded back to 16 and removed NgModule from imports.  Now getting error "./src/app/app.component.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Comment: I had AppComponent in both delarations and imports, causing a circular reference.  I removed it from imports, now it works.  Thanks for your help!